# Set: in part assignment is not a symbol

Tags: matrix, assignment

This is probably a basic question but I am new to Mathematica, so please help me out here.

I have the following piece of code:

```
lmax = 2;
arrlen = lmax + 1;
xarr[x_] = Array[x^# &, arrlen, 0];
parr[p_] = Array[p^# &, arrlen, 0];
arr[x_, p_] = Join[xarr[x], parr[p]];
mboot[x_, p_] := Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, arr[x, p], arr[x, p]]
```

Now, I want to set a few particular elements of mboot[x,p] to 0. But when I try, for example:

```
mboot[x,p][[1,1]]=0
```

I get an error saying **Set: mboot[x,p] in the part assignment is not a symbol.**

It would be great if someone could help me figure out what is going wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: Did you look at output of `mboot[x,p][[1,1]]` ? in V 12.1 it says `NonCommutativeMultiply[1,1]`. And this is not a symbol you can set to zero.

Comment: But the problem persisted even when I changed mboot[x,p[[1,1]] to 1 initially and then tried setting it to 0. So, I thought there might be something else going on that's giving the error.

Comment: You are trying to set certain values to 0? Is this after you make the matrix of values? If so, your current implementation does not make this possible since you have used `SetDelayed`, you’ll re-evaluate the value of `mboot[x, p]` each time you evaluate it. Perhaps you might use memoization to save some evaluation, but I don’t know if this holds when you call it after reassignment of certain entries to other values. Please clarify these use cases. Namely, do you want to set certain items to 0 after evaluation? Or make a sparse array initially? Give an example list of entries you’d set to 0?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to set certain values to 0 after I make a matrix of values. As I clarified below, I wanted to set the elements, the sum of whose indices is odd, to zero. I guess I could get the same result starting with a sparse array but I would probably have to use a different approach from what I have used above, since I am constructing the matrix using an outer product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is it you want to do? A simple solution is to just define a new object that you can change at will.

```
lmax = 2;
arrlen = lmax + 1;
xarr[x_] = Array[x^# &, arrlen, 0];
parr[p_] = Array[p^# &, arrlen, 0];
arr[x_, p_] = Join[xarr[x], parr[p]];
mboot[x_, p_] := Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, arr[x, p], arr[x, p]]
mutable = mboot[x, p];
mutable[[1, 1]] = 0; (* works fine *)
```

If this isn't acceptable, you'll need to add more details about what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: this solution works for me. Just to be clear, what I was specifically try to do was set elements in the matrix whose sum of indices is odd to 0, and keep the values for the other elements. So, I guess I could do that by creating a new local object as you said and setting said elements to zero using a Do loop.

Comment: There are exceptions, but you should avoid loops in Mathematica like the plague. They're inefficient and not very in line with the spirit of Mathematica. If you have the indices you want to set to 0, just do `ReplacePart[mutable, indices -> 0]`

Comment: @adithya it would be great if you could clarify your use cases..